# Как задать начальное состояние store в Redux с AJAX при его инициализации?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Доброго времени суток! Разбираюсь с react-redux и использую для запросов компонет react-thunk. Не могу не как установить начальное состояние в reducer с сервера (API). Предоставлю свой код, для лучшего понимания о чем идут речь.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import reducers from './reducers/';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import App from './App';

var store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
    axios('http://localhost:3001/api/collections')
    .then(colections => dispatch({type: 'SET_STATE_COLLECTION', data: colections.data}))
});

store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
    axios('http://localhost:3001/api/books')
    .then(books => dispatch({type: 'SET_STATE_BOOKS', data: books.data}))
});

export default store

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

Сначала в App.js { console.log(this.props) } = {{data: {books: [], collections: []}}, данные store пустые. Потом выстреливают action.type = 'SET_STATE_COLLECTION' для колекции и action.type = 'SET_STATE_BOOKS' для книг заполняя store. Мне же нужно чтобы данные изначально были в состоянии store, а они пустые и приходят по выстрелам option. Не могу понять как это сделать, как поставить изначальное состояние.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      { console.log(this.props) }
    </div>
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({data: state}), (dispatch) => ({}))(App)
```

Файлы **./reducers/**

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import collections from './collections';
import books from './books';

export default combineReducers({
    books,
    collections
})
```

**collection.js**

Здесь состояние можно установить объявив переменную ***collection*** = [...] и записав в нее данные, после же записать в функцию как параметр collectionsReducer(***state = collection*** ), но мне нужно получить их с сервера изначально, а не объявлять.

```
export default function collectionsReducer(state, action) { // reducer
        console.log(action);
        if (state === undefined) {
            return state = []
        }
        if (action.type === 'SET_STATE_COLLECTION') {
            return [...state, action.data]
        }
        return state;
    }
```

**books.js**

```
export default function booksReducer(state, action) {
        // console.log(action);
        if (state === undefined) {
            return state = []
        };
        if (action.type === 'SET_STATE_BOOKS') {
            return [...state, action.data]
        }
        return state
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста кто знает как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, лучше бы перенести запросы `api` в компонент `App`, и подключить его к `store`

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.loadBooks();
        this.props.loadCollections();
    }
    ...
}
```

Здесь `this.props.loadBooks, this.props.loadCollections` - это экшены, которые загружают данные. `componentWillMount` вызовется один раз при инициализации компонента, можно добавить флаг, который говорит о процессе загрузки

book.reducer

```
const initialState = {
    items: [],
    isLoading: true,
}
```

В самом редьюсере уже заполнять данные

```
export default function booksReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_STATE_BOOKS': {
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
            }
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

На счет изначального заполнения данных в сторе, зачем это? Вы можете в `App` проверять, есть ли данные или нет и отображать `loader` или еще что-то

Но если уж совсем извращения ( не уверен, что это рабоает, нужно проверить )

```
store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
    Promise.all([
        axios('http://localhost:3001/api/books'),
        axios('http://localhost:3001/api/collections')
    ]).then((books, collections) => {
       dispatch({type: 'SET_STATE_BOOKS', data: books});
       dispatch({type: 'SET_STATE_COLLECTION', data: colections});
       // если не будет работать, то возвращайте Promise.resolve
       // return Promise.resolve();
    }).then(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
               <App />
            </Provider>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
    })
});
```

Comment: Заполнять изначально данные в сторе для того, чтобы в render() вывести коллекцию или книги на страницу, но так не выходит т.к. данные пустые. А вы имеете ввиду проверять в render-е по loader-у, на содержание данных?

Comment: а если нужен ssr? то такая схема не прокатит...

Comment: @xFloooo Да не катит, рендер выводит при первом проходе ошибку, т.к. данных нет.

Comment: @Nick а ssr вам нужен?

Comment: xFloooo Это что то связанное с сервером? Скорее всего нет.

Comment: @Nick, да, если `isLoading === true` вы можете возвращать `null` либо вообще рисовать какой-нибудь экран загрузки с анимацией. У вас в любом случае будет простой, который надо обработать

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте books = {}, потому что, если books = undefined, будет ошибка